# LiveCharts highlight point at specific position on X axis

Tags: c#, .net, livecharts

Please, I have a functional piece of code. It hightlights point at 4th index with red brush (on X axis).

```
        var mapper = new CartesianMapper<double>()
           .X((value, index) => index)
           .Y(value => value)               
           .Fill((value, index) => index == 4 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green);
```

What should I do when I have multiple points to highlight inside int[] array?

```
int[] pointsToHighlight = new int[] {4, 5, 6};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mapper = new CartesianMapper<double>()
   .X((value, index) => index)
   .Y(value => value)               
   .Fill((value, index) => pointsToHighlight.Contains(index) ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green);
```